# Does parity violation just mean particles are chiral?

Tags: parity

Wu's experiment shows that the mirror image of a system doesn't necessarily act the same as the original system. But the experiment only mirrors the position of every particle, not the particles themselves!

Wouldn't the logical conclusion be that quarks are not just points, but rather more complex structures that have a chirality, and that when we mirror the system, we should also be mirroring the quarks themselves, rather than just their position. The 60% preference towards one end would then mean that 60% of quarks around us are left-handed, and 40% are right-handed.

Comment: Your question strings in a garland of non-sequiturs. Could you clarify? what is this position versus chirality stuff? Parity violation tells you the weak interactions treat left-chiral particles differently than relight-chiral ones.

Comment: Wait, so there are left-chiral and right-chiral particles? That's what I was trying to say: that the experiment mirrors the positions of all the particles, and the system doesn't act the same, therefore the particles aren't just points but structures that have a chirality, which we should also reverse if we want things the same.

Comment: The chirality is not in the point particle. It is in the point particle’s *interactions*.

Comment: @G.Smith I guess what I'm asking is "Could the chirality in the interactions be caused by the particles not being points, but rather having a geometrically chiral structure that we just haven't found yet?" It would seem like a nice explanation of why parity violation happens.

Comment: I have no idea. My opinion is that it sounds inelegant compared to what we have. In any case, it’s not a mainstream idea and personal theories are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a parity violation is observed when a scalar quantity, such as an interaction rate or an energy, is found to depend on pseudoscalar quantity.  For example, the "polar" vectors describing position $\vec r$ or momentum $\vec p$ change sign under reflection, but angular momentum $\vec L=\vec r\times\vec p$ does not (or changes sign twice, if you prefer).  In the Wu et al. experiment, the reaction rate (a scalar) depends on the scalar product between the nuclear spin $\vec\sigma$ and the electron momentum $\vec p$.  But the scalar product $\vec\sigma\cdot\vec p$ between an "axial vector" and a polar vector will change sign under reflection:  the reaction rate is a mixture of scalar and "pseudoscalar."  That's the parity violation.

Note that the product $\vec\sigma\cdot\vec p$ for a single particle is its helicity, not its chirality; the two are correlated only in the high-momentum limit.  A massive particle in its rest frame is equal parts left- and right-handed chirality, regardless of its spin polarization.  And decays (as in Wu et al.) must be analyzed in the rest frame of the decaying particle.  (If you object that cobalt is a big nucleus, look instead at decays of free neutrons. Or muons, even, which have no substructure at all.  The Lederman et al. discovery of parity violation in muon decay is the paper following Wu et al. in Physical Review.)

The explanation in the Standard Model for parity violation is that the charged weak current, whose vector boson is the $W^\pm$, interacts with left-chiral particles and with right-chiral antiparticles, but not vice-versa.  That explains parity violation in rest-frame decays, while a boost-dependent excess of one chirality would not.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. So particles have something called a chirality, but we don't reverse it when we mirror positions because it's not caused by them having a substructure?

Comment: I like G.Smith's comment on your question: the chirality is about the interaction, not the particle. My point was that the *spin* doesn't change sign under inversion, because spin, like all angular momenta, is an axial vector.

Comment: I see. But in theory, would it be possible that the chirality in the interaction is caused by  particles not being points, but rather structures whose mirror image is not the same? You say that "muons have no substructure at all", but how do we know that? Maybe they do, but it's too small for us to see, and if we actually mirrored that structure, it would change the chirality of the particle.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about Standard Model muons. If you want to know about experimental limits on beyond-SM physics, you should ask a new question. You'll have to be careful to phrase your question so that it's about the peer-reviewed literature, because our community has to be pretty strict about personal theories in order to keep the timecube-type questions at bay.